# ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTBILL'

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, procedure

Hi I have problem with calling store procedure on Oracle 10g server.

This is my table:

```
-- Create table
create table TMOBILE_R_BILLS
(
  ID                             VARCHAR2(50) not null,
  NO                             VARCHAR2(30) not null,
  SURNAME                        VARCHAR2(60) not null,
  NAME                           VARCHAR2(60) not null,
  BILL_MONTH                     NUMBER not null,
  VPS_TIME                       NUMBER not null,
  VPS_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT        NUMBER not null,
  VPS_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT     NUMBER not null,
  TMOBILE_TIME                   NUMBER not null,
  TMOBILE_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT    NUMBER not null,
  TMOBILE_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT NUMBER not null,
  ORANGE_TIME                    NUMBER not null,
  ORANGE_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT     NUMBER not null,
  ORANGE_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT  NUMBER not null,
  O2_TIME                        NUMBER not null,
  O2_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT         NUMBER not null,
  O2_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT      NUMBER not null,
  INTER_TIME                     NUMBER not null,
  INTER_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT      NUMBER not null,
  INTER_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT   NUMBER not null,
  ROAMING_TIME                   NUMBER not null,
  ROAMING_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT    NUMBER not null,
  ROAMING_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT NUMBER not null,
  GPRS_COUNT                     NUMBER not null,
  GPRS_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT       NUMBER not null,
  GPRS_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT    NUMBER not null,
  LM_TIME                        DATE not null,
  TOTAL_TIME                     NUMBER not null,
  TOTAL_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT      NUMBER not null,
  TOTAL_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT   NUMBER not null
)
```

here is store procedure:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTBILL(
      Id in varchar2, No in varchar2, Surname in varchar2, Name in varchar2,BillMonth in number,
      VpsTime in number, VpsPriceWithDiscount in number,VpsPriceWithoutDiscount in number,
      TmobileTime in number,TMobilePriceWithDiscount in number, TmobilePriceWithoutDiscount in number,
      OrangeTime in number, OrangePriceWithDiscount in number, OrangePriceWithoutDiscount in number,
      O2Time in number, O2PriceWithDiscount in number, O2PriceWithoutDiscount in number, InterTime in number,
      InterPriceWithDiscount in number, InterPriceWithoutDiscount in number, RoamingTime in number,
      RoamingPriceWithDiscount in number, RoamingPriceWithoutDiscount in number,
      GprsTime in number,GprsPriceWithDiscount in number, GrpsPriceWithoutDiscount in number, LmTime in date,
      TotalTime in number, TotalPriceWithDiscount in number, TotalPriceWithoutDiscount in number)
 AS
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TMOBILE_R_BILLS (ID,NO,SURNAME,NAME,BILL_MONTH,
          VPS_TIME,VPS_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT,VPS_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT,
          TMOBILE_TIME, TMOBILE_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT,TMOBILE_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT,
          ORANGE_TIME, ORANGE_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT,ORANGE_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT,
          O2_TIME,  O2_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT,  O2_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT,
          INTER_TIME,  INTER_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT,  INTER_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT,
          ROAMING_TIME, ROAMING_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT, ROAMING_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT,
          GPRS_COUNT, GPRS_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT,GPRS_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT,
          LM_TIME,
          TOTAL_TIME,  TOTAL_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT,  TOTAL_PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT)
     VALUES (Id,No,Surname, Name,BillMonth,
             VpsTime,VpsPriceWithDiscount,VpsPriceWithoutDiscount,
             TmobileTime,TMobilePriceWithDiscount,TmobilePriceWithoutDiscount,
             OrangeTime,OrangePriceWithDiscount,OrangePriceWithoutDiscount,
             O2Time, O2PriceWithDiscount, O2PriceWithoutDiscount,
             InterTime,InterPriceWithDiscount,InterPriceWithoutDiscount,
             RoamingTime,RoamingPriceWithDiscount,RoamingPriceWithoutDiscount,
             GprsTime,GprsPriceWithDiscount,GrpsPriceWithoutDiscount,
             LmTime,TotalTime,TotalPriceWithDiscount,TotalPriceWithoutDiscount);
   END;
```

This is my C# code, I use SQL bulk insert:

```
    public void InsertBills(List<CellPhoneBill> bills, int month)
    {
        var billsAsArrays = new BillDataAsArray(bills,month);

        using (var conn = new OracleConnection(GenerateConnectionString()))
        {

            var cmd = new OracleCommand
            {
                Connection = conn,
                CommandText = "INSERTBILL",
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                ArrayBindCount = billsAsArrays.Ids.Count(),
            };

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2, billsAsArrays.Ids, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("No", OracleDbType.Varchar2, billsAsArrays.Numbers, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Surname", OracleDbType.Varchar2, billsAsArrays.Surnames, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, billsAsArrays.Names, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("BillMonth", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.BillMonth, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("LmTime", OracleDbType.Date, billsAsArrays.LmTimes, ParameterDirection.Input);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("VpsTime", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.VpsTimes, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("VpsPriceWithDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.VpsPriceWithDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("VpsPriceWithoutDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.VpsPriceWithoutDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("TmobileTime", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.TmobileTimes, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("TmobilePriceWithDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.TmobilePriceWithDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("TmobilePriceWithoutDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.TmobilePriceWithoutDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("OrangeTime", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.OrangeTimes, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("OrangePriceWithDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.OrangePriceWithDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("OrangePriceWithoutDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.OrangePriceWithoutDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("O2Time", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.O2Times, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O2PriceWithDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.O2PriceWithDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O2PriceWithoutDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.O2PriceWithoutDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("InterTime", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.InterTimes, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("InterPriceWithDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.InterPriceWithDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("InterPriceWithoutDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.InterPriceWithoutDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("RoamingTime", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.RoamingTimes, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("RoamingPriceWithDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.RoamingPriceWithDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("RoamingPriceWithoutDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.RoamingPriceWithoutDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("GprsTime", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.GprsTimes, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("GprsPriceWithDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.GprsPriceWithDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("GprsPriceWithoutDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.GprsPriceWithoutDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("TotalTime", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.TotalTimes, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("TotalPriceWithDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.TotalPriceWithDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("TotalPriceWithoutDiscount", OracleDbType.Decimal, billsAsArrays.TotalPriceWithoutDiscounts, ParameterDirection.Input);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is if I test procedure in PL/SQL developer everything works good. But if I try call this procedure from C# code I get this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTBILL'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTBILL'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

**SORRY I PUBLISHED OLD AND BAD CODE, "LmTime: paramater is in C# code. But error is same. I think that something is bad with type of parameters.
In oracle all is number and in C# code all is decimal if value is number.
How can I identify problem part of code?**

Thank you for advice.

Comment: (shouldn't you have a separate time/price/total table?)  anyway, where's LM_time in the C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the order of your parameters in the C# code you posted correct? In your parameter definitions, it's the 6th parameter. In the procedure parameter list, it's 4th from the end. That would explain it if indeed your posted code is what you're getting the error with.

If not, then how I'd go about it is to modify my procedure to provide defaults for the second half of the parameter list, and take them out of your C# code. If it still fails, provide defaults for the second half of the remaining parameters, remove them from the code, and run again. Repeat until problem is identified.

Answer (score 1):

You set 29 parameters in your C# call, your stored procedure has 30 parameters. Hence `wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTBILL'`.

EDIT: You're missing the `LmTime` parameter in your C# code.

Comment: SORRY I PUBLISHED OLD AND BAD CODE, "LmTime: paramater is in C# code. But error is same. I think that something is bad with type of parameters.

In oracle all is number and in C# code all is decimal if value is number.